# WeatherLayer markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When adding the weather layer to Google Maps I find the markers to be a little overpowering.  Too many weather icons showing temps.  Specifically when you are at a closer zoom level.  Is there a way to scale it back so less information appears?

```
var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
        temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT
    });
    weatherLayer.setMap(map);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It seems there is no option or function for that.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of Anto... hmmm

Comment: Ever get an answer on this? I'm having the same problem. Way too many weather icons. Its almost comical.

Comment: Hi Anon - Sorry for the late comment.  Never found a good solution to remove some of the overlay icons.  I ended up making a toggle to show/hide them at the user's mercy.  Still curious for a better solution though.

Comment: @Anon Have you had any luck here?

Comment: @Fraze I never did. I ended up not using them and crated my own. Just made a service that grabs the weather info w/ lat and long and drop a custom marker on the map depending on weather conditions.

Comment: @Anon Great idea!!  What feed are you using to get the weather info?

Comment: @Fraze I used the OpenWeather API: http://openweathermap.org/API   Good luck!

Comment: @Anon Thanks for the help amigo!  Make your comment an actual solution and I'll award you props :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fraze, 
I never found a actual solution to this because Google doesn't provide any functionality to perform this. I did however come up with a workaround that was suitable to my needs.

I used the OpenWeather API (http://openweathermap.org/API) and created a service that grabs the weather info I need for specific predefined locations. Feed the JSON to the page and display custom markers depending on the weather condition.

I then used the following Font: http://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/ to display my markers. (Had to convert to PNG but there may be a way to bypass that).  You can also attach an infowindow to them and display even more information!

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Great solution!  I'll propose this same thing to the client and go from there... Thx again